# Automatically update text from select via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Does anyone know how to let ajax update text from a select input.
What I mean is if you select (form -> input) something, it will update/appear in a `<span>` or something.

This is what I have:

```
    <?php
echo '<select name="test">';
      for ($i=0; $i <= 20; $i++) {
        echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
      }
echo "</select>";
     ?>
```

And in the `<script>`:

```
    <script>
function upperCase()
{
var A = document.getElementById('test').value;
var B = document.getElementById('txtHint1').value;

C = A * B
document.getElementById('result').value = C; 
} 
    </script>
```

And where I want to show it:

```
<span id="txtHint1" onchange="upperCase()"></span>
```

I hope you understand me.

Comment: Bind the `onchange` event to the `<select>`, not the `<span>`

Comment: I would assume from your JavaScript code that you want to show the result of your multiplication in a span with id of "result" not in the span with id of "txtHint1", as the latter contains one of the operands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several errors in your original question. The first of which is here:

```
echo "<select name="test">;
```

Since it's a double-quoted string, you'll need to escape the double quotes around test, or surround the string in single quotes. You're also missing a closing quote. Is should look something like this:

```
echo '<select name="test">';
```

Also, rather than binding your onchange event to where you want to show the results, bind it to the element that, when *changed*, you want your JavaScript to execute. In this case, that would be your select. Now we're up to this:

```
echo '<select name="test" onchange="upperCase()">';
```

This line: `C = A * B` should look more like:

```
var C = A * B;
```

Additionally, your code is attempting to set the value of an element with ID `result`. According to your post, it seems that you may want to change that to `txtHint1`.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the errors. I'm sorry. I wasn't looking... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is your scenario:

- User selects an option from a drop down box
- Once they have selected their option, the value of that option multiplied by your 'txtHint1' span is shown in the 'result' span

First, you don't need ajax to do that, just JavaScript, which I'm sure you meant. Next, you don't want onchange on your 'txtHint1' span, because there's nothing to change there. You want onchange to be on your 'select' element. You were very close in your code.

```
function upperCase()
{
    var a = document.getElementById('test').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('txtHint1').value;
    var c = a * b;

    document.getElementById('result').value = c;
}

<select name="text" onchange="upperCase()">YOUR PHP CODE<select>
```

I didn't test this, but it should work.